# SS7 attack possibilities

Tags: ss7

I'm new to SS7 security and have been looking into SS7 hacks. What I was wondering was if there are other ways hackers can gain access to SS7 networks other than creating an app using the SS7 SDK because that's what most of videos I've watched have said. For example, since SMS uses SS7, I was wondering if an attack can be done using sms messages.

Comment: Unlikely. Do note there is no "SS7 SDK" as I can see. SS7 is a private network, like the Internet, you need to find someone to get you connected. Unlike the Internet which is designed for everyone, SS7 is designed for phone companies. If you are not a phone company you will not get connected because there is no reason to connect you. Sometimes phone companies get hacked and hackers use their connection to SS7. I'm not sure if they've ever started a fake phone company to get connected.

Comment: @user253751 You don't need to hack into SS/. There are companies selling access to SS7 network: https://www.thebureauinvestigates.com/stories/2021-12-06/swiss-tech-company-boss-accused-of-selling-mobile-network-access-for-spying

Comment: SMS over LTE does not use SS7.

Comment: @default SS7 is never used by phones directly, therefore you could say no matter if you use 2G 3G 4G 5G sending an SMS will not make use of SS7 from the user perspective. But if you send an SMS to a user of a different provider in the backend most likely the SMS will be transferred via SS7 from your provider to the provider you have sent the SMS to.